# is it possible to join collections with linq

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, join

Linq supports most of the MongoDB operations. But I'm confused that does Linq support join collections in MongoDB?

If supports, could you give an example?

If doesn't support, must we apply mapreduce operations to join collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq, both syntactically and via the existing method class, does support [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operations.

However, since `Queryable` objects get converted under the hood into queries based on database driver, you would need to look into MongoDB for whether *Mongo* supports those join operations.

Note that if it doesn't it's always possible to perform certain operations in memory, which is often necessary when method calls get involved - just as [`.AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which spite out an `IEnumerable`. Since the extension methods on `IEnumerable` perform `foreach` loops instead of adding `Expression` data, any further calls get executed on objects in-memory.

Comment: thanks for answer. Mongo doesn't support join operations on its' own shell. So, to make join, I have to do mapreduce operations. If Linq could do join on MongoDB, it would be very nice.

Comment: If Mongo doesn't support it, go the `AsEnumerable` route - it pulls everything into memory and performs operations in .NET.

Comment: I'm searching usage of AsEnumerable on MongoDB. Thanks again.